# How does Google App Engine (GAE) Java server check if it a backend?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, backend

I want the server to know if it's a backend or not preferably already during

```
contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent event)
```

(but less preferably when the first HTTP request arrives).

I tried

```
BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService().getCurrentBackend()
```

but it is always returning null (at least locally in Google Eclipse plugin) even when it is a backend and even in the context of an incoming http request!

Answer (score 1):

Update.

```
    BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService().getCurrentBackend()
```

DOES work on product but not in the Eclipse plugin.  Would still like a version that works for both. Perhaps this is just a bug:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8058&thanks=8058&ts=1346615492